# How to change axis-label color in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have tried

```
... + xlab("New label", colour="darkgrey")
```

and

```
... + xlab("New label", color="darkgrey")
```

But it says this argument is unused. I look into `?xlab`, but it doesn't include any color parameter. Is it possible to change it? How?

Comment: Related question (may be useful to have a cross-link): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075446/how-to-get-axis-ticks-labels-with-different-colors-within-a-single-axis-for-a-gg

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since **ggplot2** 0.9.2, the syntax has become:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5,y = 1:5)
p + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "red"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "blue"))
```

The [tidyverse](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) page is a good starting point for learning about all the options.

Note that the old syntax based on `opts` has been deprecated. There is detailed [transition guide](https://ggplot2-dev.googlegroups.com/attach/5aa16afece3d5bc6/theme0.html?gda=9XgBzEYAAABCncUW0npTUN_veVgl3inYi0oNsf4Sjxsz8g3AimkTHy2Q5nwgitdzQrQMmMK7aytx40jamwa1UURqDcgHarKEE-Ea7GxYMt0t6nY0uV5FIQ&view=1&part=4) for updating your code.

Comment: @PatrickT Thanks! I should be better about updating my answers, but there's only so much time in the day. In the future, feel free to simply suggest an edit to my answer directly with the updated syntax, I'll get a notification and can approve it directly.

Comment: @PatrickT: after 5.5 Years I have seen that  p + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "red"), axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "blue")) this works.

Answer (score 1):

This changes both the x and y axis:

```
theme(text=element_text(color="red"))
```

This also changes the labels of the ticks:

```
theme(text=element_text(color="red"),axis.text=element_text(color="blue"))
```