# How to get axis ticks labels with different colors within a single axis for a ggplot graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider a simple ggplot2 graph

```
library(ggplot2) 
dat <- data.frame(name=c("apple", "orange", "plum"),value=c(3,8,2),outlier=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))
ggplot(dat)+geom_point(aes(x=value,y=name))
```

[image]

Is there a way to modify styles attributes of the axis y labels (say color) conditionally, for example depending on the `outlier` column in `dat`?

The result would be something like

[image]

On a graph with a large number of items this feature wold greatly improve the graph readability and impact.

Comment: I don't agree with your last sentence. If you want to highlight "outliers", colour the points. Regarding the question: Yes, it's possible. However, not easily, because ggplot2 was not designed to do this. Thus, you'd probably have to generate the grob and hack away at it.

Comment: Actually this feature has been requested by our graphic designer. The actual graph is much denser than this simple example, with  long labels on the axis. We use the color modification  to slightly lighten the names of the non-outlier points. The outlier names pop to the eyes, which is the very aim of the graph. That's fairly effective for communication, really ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609716/changing-format-of-some-axis-labels-in-ggplot2-according-to-condition)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simpler way (IMO) to do this is just create a conditional color vector and parse it into `axis.text.y`

```
dat <- data.frame(name=c("apple", "orange", "plum"),value=c(3,8,2),outlier=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))
colvec <- character(dim(dat)[1])
colvec <- ifelse(dat$outlier, "red", "black")

library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(dat) +
geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=value,y=name)) +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour=colvec))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks! A little extra if the graph is plotted with a `facet_grid(...,scales="free_y")` this method does not seems to apply anymore as the color vector is recycled through the facets. an idea for that case ?

Comment: That could be a new question I guess

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is as good as colouring the outlier point itself, but you can hack away at the grob:

```
p <- ggplot(dat)+geom_point(aes(x=value,y=name))
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

#I found this by using str(g) and looking for "axis.text.y.text"
#there is probably a clever way of automating this
g[[1]][[2]]$children$axis$grobs[[1]]$gp$col <- c("grey50", "red", "grey50")

plot(g)
```

[image]

Doing this conditionally is possible using something like `c("grey50", "red")[dat$outlier]` assuming the row order is as needed. However, I can only reiterate that you probably should create a different graph if you think you need something like this.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely the way to go. I will work to figure out how to automate the localization of the grob. I am yet not very familiar with the gtable structure.

Comment: For unconditional plot you could just do `ggplot(dat) +
geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=value,y=name)) +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour=c("grey50", "red", "grey50")))`