# colour single ggplot axis item

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

I have created a chart and am wanting to colour one of the x-axis items based on a variable. I have seen this post ([How to get axis ticks labels with different colors within a single axis for a ggplot graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075446/how-to-get-axis-ticks-labels-with-different-colors-within-a-single-axis-for-a-gg)), but am struggling to apply it to my dataset.
[image]

```
df1 <- data.frame(var=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"), 
                  val=c(99,120,79,22,43,53,12,27,31),
                  type=c("alpha","alpha","alpha","bravo","bravo","bravo","charlie","charlie","charlie"))

myvar="a"

ggplot(df1,aes(x=reorder(var,-val), y=val,fill=type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Any tips on how to make the x-axis value red when it is equal to `myvar`?

**Update:** Thanks to @ddiez for some guidance. I finally came around to the fact that i would have to reorder prior to plotting. I also should have made my original example with data.table, so am not sure if this would influenced original responses. I modified my original dataset to be a data.table and used the following code to achieve success.

```
df1 <- data.table(var=c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","b","c"), 
                  val=c(99,120,79,22,43,53,12,27,31),
                  type=c("alpha","alpha","alpha","bravo","bravo","bravo","charlie","charlie","charlie"))

myvar="a"

df1[,axisColour := ifelse(var==myvar,"red","black")]
df1$var <- reorder(df1$var,-df1$val,sum)

setkey(df1,var,type)

ggplot(df1,aes(x=var, y=val,fill=type)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour=df1[,axisColour[1],by=var][,V1]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant solution but a quick hack (requires you to know the final order) would be:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=reorder(var,-val), y=val,fill=type)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour=c("black","black","red")))
```

A solution using the variable `myvar` (yet, there may be better ways):

```
# reorder the factors in the data.frame (instead of in situ).
df1$var=reorder(df1$var, -df1$val)

# create a vector of colors for each level.
mycol=rep("black", nlevels(df1$var))
names(mycol)=levels(df1$var)

# assign the desired ones a different color.
mycol[myvar]="red"

ggplot(df1,aes(x=var, y=val,fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour=mycol))
```

Comment: While addressing this specific example, it doesn't answer the original question, which is how to do it based on a match with `myvar` where the value could be changed.

Comment: I haven't used quite your approach for the colour vectors but you gave some good guidance. I have updated my question to reflect my answer, but I am not sure if yours or mine is a cleaner/faster approach.

Comment: @Dan if you have an alternative answer maybe you can post it as a proper answer (instead inline the question), so that it can be voted.