# color axis the same as the points

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the x axis be colored the same as the points.

Ideally, I'd like to not have to manually set colors and my real dataset has 20 points in each facet.

```
d = data.frame(x = c("A","B","C"),y = c(1,2,3), color = c("A","B","C"))
    ggplot(d, aes(x= x, y = y, color = color))+geom_point()
```

Comment: The entire x-axis, or the axis labels?

Comment: If you mean the labels, the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24075446/how-to-get-axis-ticks-labels-with-different-colors-within-a-single-axis-for-a-gg

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I'd like to not have to manually set the color with col vec. Is there a way to dynamically get the colors the points use and color the x labels the same?

Comment: *"color the x labels the same"* I don't understand what you mean. Do you want to colour the axis *labels*? The *line*? If so how? And why? Can you provide a mock-up of your expected output plot?

Comment: If you look at the plot the points are colored. I'd like the x axis labels to be same color as the points.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
myColors <- brewer.pal(length(levels(as.factor(d$color))),"Set1")
names(myColors) <- levels(as.factor(d$color))
colScale <- scale_colour_manual(name = "color",values = myColors)
ggplot(d, aes(x= x, y = y, color = color))+geom_point()+ theme(axis.text.x =element_text( colour = myColors))+colScale
```